# Plot complex integration contour

Tags: plotting, legending

I want to draw the the contour

```
{z, 0, -2, -2 + I 10^3, I 10^3, 0}
```

and maybe highlight different parts with different colours. I can’t find the suitable function.

Comment: `ComplexListPlot[{0, -2, -2 + I 10^3, I 10^3, 0}, Joined -> True]`?

Comment: And perhaps add options like: `PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 0.5}, All}, AspectRatio -> 2`